# How to remove space betwen node icon and node text in XtraTreeList

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, treelist

I have a WinForm app with tree list. Nodes in list have image index and TreeList binded to image list. 
The problem is I could not find the way to remove space between icon and text.

[image]

if sombody can help me, I will be grateful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like you have selected an empty image.

The treelist supports a `StateImageList` and a `SelectImageList`. Make sure you are only using the one you require. (Try setting the StateImageList property back to "(None)")

[image]